# Why does typing https:// doesn't work?

Tags: wordpress, https

I have a website that I'm working on to pass from http to https. A month ago, I've went through all pages on the website and changed the links in the page's content using the Wordpress CMS back-end editor. When I typed https:// in the address, I could see on the console a lot of Mixed Content errors related to links on files that I don't access to, so I passed this all to the back-end guy in my company to deal with.

Today, someone pointed out that the website is still not secure and if you type https:// it will default to http://. I've tried doing this in Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer, and them all default back to http://. The person that pointed this problem said that, since we already have the certificate, this should be happening because some part of the website is still not secure.

How can I find where is this issue happening?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/moving-to-https-on-wordpress/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to enable the secure site feature from your hosting first the "SLL", but since you mentioned it is already enabled. then you will need to use a plugin to enforce the secure website on all pages, you can try https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/